# IFilter code with ReadLine() implemented?

Tags: c#, ifilter, textreader

Doers anyone know of an `IFilter` wrapper class that implements `ReadLine()`.

I'm currently using this [Code Project IFilter Wrapper](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13391/Using-IFilter-in-C) which is excellent and inherits `TextReader` but it doesn't contain an implementation for `ReadLine()`. Having had a look at the `Read()` method it doesn't look easy or something that can be done quickly.

Is there a quick and easy way to implement this that I'm just missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem as you, so I had to create my own implementation (basically checked available implementations and resources for filters, and then hammered something together).

It is also implemented as TextReader, overrides Read method, so ReadLine works automatically.

Code can be found here: https://github.com/MarianPolacek/MP.FilterReader

Comment: thanks - it came a bit too late but good to know for the future.